# Paste0 in R returns strange values for dates

Tags: r, date, dataset, paste

I have a csv file that serves as a template for a bigger job, the contents are below:

```
date_field,string1,string2,numeric1,numeric2  
2019-03-09 00:00,abc,def,,0  
2019-03-09 00:02,ghi,jkl,458.4,8444
```

I pulled it into a variable called "testing" and was playing around with paste and paste0, and did the following:

```
testing <- read.csv('C:\\Users\\blahblahblah...\\template.csv')
values <- paste(testing[1])
print(values)
```

the result:

```
[1] "1:2"
```

if I run a print on the original variable, the result is dead normal:

```
print(testing[1])

        date_field
1 2019-03-09 00:00
2 2019-03-09 00:02
```

I've been googling for about an hour, and can't figure out what's wrong. Is "value" not the right type?

Many thankZ

Answer (score 0):

Your `date_field` got imported as a factor. When you use `read.csv()`, set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. This imports your strings as characters.  Your code behaves as expected if `date_field` is a character. If you have `date_field` as a POSIXct or Date object, you will also have weird results.

```
testing <- read.csv('C:\\Users\\blahblahblah...\\template.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: thank you! Definite improvement over the previous: [1] "c(\"2019-03-09 00:00\", \"2019-03-09 00:02\")" Hwhy the c and the backslashes though?

Comment: so behind the scenes a data.frame is a list, and asking for `testing[1]` is asking for the first element in the list, which is a vector. The `c()` function creates a vector. backslash is an escape character that allows you to have quote marks inside a string. If you `unlist` your column and `collapse` your paste, you might get what you want: `paste(unlist(testing[1]), collapse = ",")`